# Fragment transition using add and replace

Tags: android

I am having a situation Fragment A  is used Add but in FragmentB I used replace for FragmentC.

FragmentA--Add---FragmentB---Repace --FragmentC

When i clicked back from fragment C it brings me back to Fragment A.

**Note** : all fragments added in backstack

**Required behavior** : When pressed back from fragmentC it must come back to FragmentB. Instead it brings back to fragmentA

Plz help.

Regards

Comment: This is working exactly as it should. What did you want exactly?

Comment: Please tell us about your desired behaviour. What should happen when you press back from Fragment C?